# The stakeholders - Authors, peer reviewers and editors

Tags: word-usage

> Authors, peer reviewers and editors all have roles and responsibilities during the review process. As Jayashree Rajagopalan, co-chair of the 2021 PRW steering committee notes ‘Peer review is more than just a process. It is a teeming, thriving ecosystem that functions as a whole due to — and despite — the distinct roles played by each of the **stakeholders** involved in it’.

> Source:T[he Lancet](https://info.thelancet.com/the-lancet-webinars-peer-review?utm_campaign=lancetwebinars21&utm_source=homepage)

The use of the word "stakeholders" is unusual to me as it refers to "Authors, peer reviewers and editors."  Does the word simply mean "people who share the same interest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=stakeholders+meaning),

The definition is:

> a person with an interest or concern in something, especially a business.

It says "especially", doesn't mean it has to be in business. Generally would be "a person with an interest or concern in something".

So you're correct about "people who share the same interest".

Also as @JackO'Flaherty mentioned in the comments:

> The root word is "stake" - M-W A personal interest or involvement. Someone who has an interest in something has a stake in it, so they are a stakeholder.

Comment: The root word is "stake" - M-W  A personal interest or involvement. Someone who has an interest in something has a stake in it, so they are a stakeholder.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty True! That is a very good explanation in short!